# Why this htaccess file doesnot give expected results?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to capture the string in the url, `http://localhost/framework/red` ..
I have the following htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(^/)*$ index.php?t=$1
```

I have a file index.php in the framework directory.
browser returns me with Object not found! eror and the log says File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/framework/sa..
How can I store the string after framework/ in a variable using (^/)..

Comment: I think you mixed up `[…]` and `(…)`.

Comment: Not sure that regex is matching correctly, try ^(.*)/$ instead of ^(^/)*$. This way anything between localhost/framework/*HERE*/ will then send the HERE value to the t param. It would be easier if we could see your entire URL structure.

Comment: I had always been wondering what advantage is there in using querystring instead of PATH_INFO... (By the way you may want the `[QSA]` flag for the rule)

Answer (score 0):

`^(^/)*$` isn't a valid regular expression. It doesn't match anything, thus the rule never gets applied and you're going to get 404 responses. You're probably looking for something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `^(^/)*$` actually is valid. It matches the strings `""` and `"/"`.